Python: sort individual lines in a multiline string
Is there a way to sort a multiline string alphabetically by individual line, while also keeping the output one multiline string?
Input string:
"First line.
A sentence here.
Other Line.
Different sentence."

Output string:
"A sentence here.
Different sentence.
First line.
Other Line."


You could split your multi-line string by newline (\n), then use the built-in sorted function, and reassemble the result into a multi-line string:
multi_line_str = """First line.
A sentence here.
Other Line.
Different sentence."""

"\n".join(sorted(multi_line_str.split("\n")))

